# How to move this group/concat logic into a function?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Given a column of integers

```sql
ids AS (
  SELECT
    id
  FROM
    UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) AS id)
```

I'd like to convert them into the following (batched) string representations:

```
"1,2,3,4,5"
"6,7"
```

Currently, I do this as follows:

```sql
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(CAST(id AS STRING), ',')
FROM (
  SELECT
    DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER() - 1, 5) batch,
    id
  FROM
    ids)
GROUP BY
  batch
```

Since I use this on multiple occasions, I'd like to move this into a [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions).

Is this possible, and if so how?

(I guess, since we can't pass the table (`ids`), we'd need to pass an `ARRAY<INT64>`, but that would be ok.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might consider below 2 approches.

##### UDF

- returns result as *ARRAY<STRING>*.

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION batched_string(ids ARRAY<INT64>) AS (
  ARRAY(
    SELECT STRING_AGG('' || id) FROM (
      SELECT DIV(offset, 5) batch, id 
        FROM UNNEST(ids) id WITH offset
    ) GROUP BY batch
  )
);

SELECT * FROM UNNEST(batched_string([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));
```

##### [Table functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/table-functions)

- return result as a *Table*.
- note that a table function shouldn't be a temp function.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE FUNCTION `your-project.dataset.batched_string`(ids ARRAY<INT64>) AS (
  SELECT STRING_AGG('' || id) batched FROM (
    SELECT DIV(offset, 5) batch, id 
      FROM UNNEST(ids) id WITH offset
  ) GROUP BY batch
);

SELECT * FROM `your-project.dataset.batched_string`([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);
```

[image]